# Increase space in var mount point

Tags: rhel, mount, lvm

My /var lvm space is full. I have 500 GB space in /dev/sdb filesystem which is already mounted to  /mnt/data point and it has data in it.
I want to move some space from /dev/sdb to /var lvm without destroying already present data in /mnt/data.
Please guide.

[lsblk Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1FS8.png)

[df -h screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bok3i.png)

Comment: Please use copy and paste to post the text. Pictures of text are not a substitute.

Comment: You should park the data currently on /mnt/data somewhere, add /dev/sdb to the volume group used by teh /var lvm, and then increase the size of /var. You can also allocate a separate logical volume for the /mnt/data stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [blocks](https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme) to convert `/dev/sdb` into an LVM physical volume, with the *data* filesystem placed into an LVM logical volume. Once the *data* filesystem is in an LVM logical volume, you'd be able to shrink it and then allocate the freed space to `/var` **if** the `/var` logical volume does not use contiguous allocation.

**Warning: With disk operations such as this, data integrity is *never* guaranteed. Although the data should not be destroyed by following this procedure, I highly recommend having a backup before proceeding. You just never know what might happen.**

1. Un-mount the *data* filesystem: `umount /mnt/data`.
2. Convert the *data* partition to an LVM physical volume: `blocks to-lvm --join=VOLGROUP /dev/sdb`
3. Run `lvs` to get the name of the new LV.
4. Edit `/etc/fstab` so that `/mnt/data` is mounted from the new LV.
5. Shrink the new *data* LV (using 20GB as an example): `lvresize -r -L -20G /dev/VOLGROUP/NAME_OF_NEW_LV`
6. Grow the *var* LV: `lvresize -r -L +20G /dev/VOLGROUP/var`
7. Mount the *data* filesystem: `mount /mnt/data`